# Javascript regular expression: match any not-word except allowed special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, special-characters, regex-negation

I've been trying to find a way to do this for about an hour now, but maybe I'm not phrasing it right.

I want to match all special characters EXCEPT -_+#&!

example set:

`` !@#$%^&µ*&+=_-()}{~`¡€$* ``

regex should select:

`` @$%^µ*=()}{~`¡€$* ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minute after I posted this, I discovered the solution.

`/([^\w!&+=_-])/g`

http://www.regexr.com/3a50t

For future reference, if you're looking to exclude all special characters except a specific set of special characters, you could:

`/([^\w__theSpecialCharactersYouWantToAllow__])/g`

If I'm wrong let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer by Andrew will select one character, you may wish to match more than one character:

```
/([^\w!&+=_-]+)/g
```

EDIT:

In the case of validation (which the OP is likely doing), it wouldn't matter, but if you are cleansing the string of these characters - that is when you would want to match one or more.

<strike>Also you're removing alphanumeric characters with \w, and I'm not sure if you wanted that.</strike>

Actually, you're wanting only special characters, so that's correct!

Comment: Reason why I'm only looking to match 1 character is that this is a test within a function that will return false if there is an illegal character   function(){ if(regex.test(string){ return false'} }

Answer (score 0):

This could work too :)

```
var regex = new RegExp(/([^-_+#&!])/g),
    str = "!@#$%^&µ*&+=_-()}{~`¡€$*";

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: Originally, I downvoted this answer because I, however long ago, misread this: http://goo.gl/xPBv4F to mean that you shouldn't use wrapper objects for primitive types -- without taking into consideration that you could be type casting.  That being said, your print function would attempt to print the results of your match... like with an actual printer. Maybe you meant console.log?

Comment: I ran through this on the command line using `rhino` and it got fussy when I used `console.log`. I've only seen `console.log` in node.js applications, which your question didn't state what flavor of JavaScript it was. Regardless, printing out the results is trivial.

Comment: console.log is a builtin method for browsers- if you open up dev tools in chrome (cmd/ctrl + shift + I ), then hit esc, then type console.log('log a message'); the console will log a message. If you're getting an error, just add this to the top of the script : var console = { log: function(thing){ return thing; }}